# me sale error en esto -->set_time_limit()<-- Bloqueado

Tags: php, pdf, servidor

quiero imprimir un documento que es generado desde la web a PDF, pero no medejea que puedo hacer alguien me puede ayudar.
les dejo todo lo que me sale  cuando quiero imprimir, esto sale en una nueva pantalla. funcion bloqueada en php que hago ayúdenme.

```
Warning: set_time_limit() has been disabled for security reasons in /home/u461708868/public_html/pdf/html2pdf.class.php on line 12
TCPDF ERROR: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file
```

Comment: Comparte el código y no sólo el mensaje de error. Así será más fácil ayudarte.

Comment: ' */
ini_set("memory_limit","256M");//memoria maxima para cargar el archivo---------------------
set_time_limit(500);//tiempo maximo de ejecucion en segundos--------------------------------------
if (!defined('__CLASS_HTML2PDF__')) {'

Comment: 'set_time_limit(500);' es lo que mesabilitarón por motivo de seguridad que puedo hacer

Comment: Siempre tienes la opción de `Editar` la pregunta para agregar y/o quitar contenido.. en lugar de agregar mas contexto acá en los comentarios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entiendo que estas usando los servicios de un proveedor de hosting y éste ha deshabilitado la ejecución de set_time_limit para prevenir que los scripts php consuman la memoria del servidor.

Al no tener disponible el archivo de configuración **php.ini** la solución que veo es que solicites a tu proveedor la ejecución de set_time_limit a 90 segundos o cambies de proveedor.

Answer (score 0):

Yo eliminaria la línea del time_limit(500)  y optimizaría la consulta para reducirla al límite máximo que permita el proveedor.

500 segundos es demasiado tiempo para un script. No se el pdf que necesitas generar pero deberían ser segundos.